# SQL Server - How the same page can be exclusively (X) locked by two processes?

Tags: sql-server, deadlock

If I deciphered the following deadlock graph correctly, it looks like two processes (SPIDs: 216 and 209) own the exclusive (X) lock on the very same page:

The XDL `<resource-list>` shows

```xml
<pagelock
    fileid="1"
    pageid="17410848"
    dbid="21"
    subresource="FULL"
    objectname="33bd93e0-f5b2-43f6-93ca-56bbe6493e0c.dbo.sync_publishers2"
    id="lock630b1d5380"
    mode="X"
    associatedObjectId="72057608416264192">
    <owner-list>
        <owner
            id="process90763f08c8"
            mode="X"
            requestType="wait" />
    </owner-list>
    <waiter-list>
        <waiter
            id="process861129bc28"
            mode="X"
            requestType="wait" />
    </waiter-list>
</pagelock>
```

And a bit further down

```xml
<pagelock
    fileid="1"
    pageid="17410848"
    dbid="21"
    subresource="FULL"
    objectname="33bd93e0-f5b2-43f6-93ca-56bbe6493e0c.dbo.sync_publishers2"
    id="lock630b1d5380"
    mode="X"
    associatedObjectId="72057608416264192">
    <owner-list>
        <owner
            id="process90763f04e8"
            mode="X" />
    </owner-list>
    <waiter-list>
        <waiter
            id="process90763f08c8"
            mode="X"
            requestType="wait" />
    </waiter-list>
</pagelock>
```

[image: deadlock graph]

How it is even possible and what does it mean?

The full deadlock definition is available here: http://pastebin.com/A4Te3Chx.

**UPD:** I've filed an item on Microsoft Connect to try to gather authoritative response: https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/Feedback/Details/3119334.

Answer (score 11):

This just means that there was a queue waiting on that lock.

You can reproduce it with the following (run the setup and then tran 1. You then have 15 seconds to start tran 2 and tran 3 in sequence in different connections).

**Setup**

```
USE tempdb

CREATE TABLE T
  (
     X INT PRIMARY KEY WITH(ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = OFF),
     Filler AS CAST('A' AS CHAR(8000)) PERSISTED
  );

INSERT INTO T VALUES (1), (2), (3);
```

**Tran 1**

```
SET XACT_ABORT ON
USE tempdb -- t1

BEGIN TRAN

UPDATE T   SET X = X WHERE X = 1

WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:15' 


--See what locks are granted just before the deadlock
SELECT resource_description,
        request_status,
        request_session_id,
        X
FROM   sys.dm_tran_locks tl
        LEFT JOIN T WITH(NOLOCK)
            ON sys.fn_PhysLocFormatter(T.%% physloc%%) = '(' + RTRIM(resource_description) + ':0)'
WHERE  resource_associated_entity_id = (SELECT partition_id
                                        FROM   sys.partitions
                                        WHERE  object_id = object_id('T'));

RAISERROR ('',0,1) WITH NOWAIT;

UPDATE T  SET X = X WHERE X = 3

WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:20'
ROLLBACK
```

**Tran 2**

```
SET XACT_ABORT ON
USE tempdb -- t2

BEGIN TRAN

UPDATE T SET X = X WHERE X = 2

UPDATE T  SET X = X WHERE X = 1

WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:20'
ROLLBACK
```

**Tran 3**

```
SET XACT_ABORT ON

USE tempdb -- t3
BEGIN TRAN

UPDATE T  SET    X = X WHERE  X = 3    

UPDATE T SET    X = X WHERE  X = 1

ROLLBACK
```

The result of the query against `tran_locks` immediately before requesting the lock that will cause deadlock shows

```
+----------------------+----------------+--------------------+---+
| resource_description | request_status | request_session_id | X |
+----------------------+----------------+--------------------+---+
| 4:416                | GRANT          |                 61 | 1 |
| 4:416                | WAIT           |                 64 | 1 |
| 4:416                | WAIT           |                 65 | 1 |
| 4:418                | GRANT          |                 64 | 2 |
| 4:419                | GRANT          |                 65 | 3 |
+----------------------+----------------+--------------------+---+
```

The deadlock graph I received is as follows.

Though it says the deadlock victim was waiting on a lock owned by tran 2 this is not actually the case. At the time of the deadlock the lock was owned by tran 1 and tran 2 was first in line for it before tran 3.

[image]

The deadlock graph XML shows this as it has two nodes for the same resource (page 416) and in one the "owner" has a `requestType="wait"`

```xml
<resource-list>
    <pagelock
        fileid="4"
        pageid="416"
        dbid="2"
        subresource="FULL"
        objectname="tempdb.dbo.T"
        id="lock2486d8c4380"
        mode="X"
        associatedObjectId="936748728230805504">
        <owner-list>
            <owner
                id="process2486ba0cca8"
                mode="X"
                requestType="wait" />
        </owner-list>
        <waiter-list>
            <waiter
                id="process2485370c8c8"
                mode="X"
                requestType="wait" />
        </waiter-list>
    </pagelock>
    <pagelock
        fileid="4"
        pageid="416"
        dbid="2"
        subresource="FULL"
        objectname="tempdb.dbo.T"
        id="lock2486d8c4380"
        mode="X"
        associatedObjectId="936748728230805504">
        <owner-list>
            <owner
                id="process2485370c4e8"
                mode="X" />
        </owner-list>
        <waiter-list>
            <waiter
                id="process2486ba0cca8"
                mode="X"
                requestType="wait" />
        </waiter-list>
    </pagelock>
    <pagelock
        fileid="4"
        pageid="419"
        dbid="2"
        subresource="FULL"
        objectname="tempdb.dbo.T"
        id="lock248636ace80"
        mode="X"
        associatedObjectId="936748728230805504">
        <owner-list>
            <owner
                id="process2485370c8c8"
                mode="X" />
        </owner-list>
        <waiter-list>
            <waiter
                id="process2485370c4e8"
                mode="X"
                requestType="wait" />
        </waiter-list>
    </pagelock>
</resource-list>
```

Comment: if we consider transaction #2 (SPID 64) should not it own and wait two _different_ pages (corresponding to X=1 and X=2)? Why does is look like SPID 64 owns and waits X lock on the very same page 416?!

Comment: @EugeneD.Gubenkov at the time of the deadlock it does own a lock on page 418 for x = 2. You can see this from the tran_locks output. That resource isn't relevant  to the deadlock as none of the other transactions are requesting it so doesn't appear in the deadlock graph. Why it looks like it owns and waits for an X lock on the very same page is because it is a queue. T1 owns the resource, T2 is waiting for it and T3 is also waiting for it but needs to wait for T2 to get its request granted and release the lock first.

Comment: did I understand correctly that "owner" does not always mean owner, sometimes it mean waiter?

Comment: @EugeneD.Gubenkov yes. The true owner is the one without a request type of wait in the XML. All tran 2 owns of page 416 is a place in the queue ahead of t3.

Comment: That's very interesting! It would be great if you have some references to documentation... Do you?

Comment: @EugeneD.Gubenkov - No. I didn't find any documentation on the XDL format at all. So this answer was just based on a theory and then coming up with a repro to test that theory. The "relaxed FIFO" queue for locks is documented here though https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/psssql/2009/06/02/sql-server-lock-manager-and-relaxed-fifo/

Comment: @EugeneD.Gubenkov this page https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188246.aspx about analyzing deadlock graphs states: Owner ID = Transaction ID for the processes which are using transactions and currently waiting on a lock.

Comment: @SteveFord, thanks, but I guess it's not relevant piece, with owner id is shown on a process node and shows transaction ID, it has nothing to do with resources owning as far as I can see from the document.